# Using grep with wc in shell script if block

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a shell script that counts the number of occurrences of a string in a file and take some action based on it.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ grep "\s*oplocks\s=" sample.txt | wc -l = 5 ]
then
    echo "cnt equals 5"
else
    echo "cnt not 5"
fi
```

Along with `grep`, I also want to count the number of occurrences so I am using `wc -l`. How can I put this in a `if` statement?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to count all occurrences or only count _lines_ that contain the pattern? That is, if a line has the pattern twice should it count once or twice? If the former then you can use `grep -o pattern file | wc  -l`

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion when I say "former" in my last comment I'm referring to the first sentence (i.e. "to count all occurrences").

Comment: If a line has multiple occurrences, then I want it to be counted once.

Comment: In that case you should use `grep -c pattern file` (no need for `wc`) as another user suggested .. until I scared them into deleting their answer with my lines vs occurrences query.   "Sorry" to whoever that was. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command substitution `$()` and `-eq`: arithmetic comparison:

```
if [ $(grep 'something' file | wc -l) -eq 5 ]
    then
       echo equal
    else
       echo not equal
fi
```

Comment: `if [ "$(grep -c 'something' file)" -eq 5 ]` is a better alternative

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-c` argument to grep and skip `wc` altogether.  Also, you can use an arithmetic context to avoid -eq and the like.

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $(grep -c 'pattern' sample.txt) == 5 )); then
    echo "5 occurances"
fi

exit
```